# Windows Programming : Insert List Box into Windows Application using C++

Tags: c++, windows, list, box

I wish to add a list box into my windows application which will be used as a GUI.  I have an example from Microsoft what shows me how to add a list box inserted into a child window.  Can someone show me an example of adding a list box into a parent windows application?

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_LIST, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_LIST));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                OutputDebugStringW(L"inside About Before\n");
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                OutputDebugStringW(L"inside About After\n");
                break;
            case IDM_LISTBOX:
                OutputDebugStringW(L"inside ListBox Before\n");
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_LISTBOX), hWnd, ListBox);
                OutputDebugStringW(L"inside ListBox After\n");
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This section handles the list box within the child window.

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK ListBox(HWND hDlg, UINT message,WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        // Add items to list. 
        HWND hwndList = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LISTBOX);
        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(Roster); i++)
        {
            int pos = (int)SendMessage(hwndList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0,
                (LPARAM)Roster[i].achName);
            // Set the array index of the player as item data.
            // This enables us to retrieve the item from the array
            // even after the items are sorted by the list box.
            SendMessage(hwndList, LB_SETITEMDATA, pos, (LPARAM)i);
        }
        // Set input focus to the list box.
        SetFocus(hwndList);
        return TRUE;
    }

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDOK:
        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return TRUE;

        case IDC_LISTBOX:
        {
            switch (HIWORD(wParam))
            {
            case LBN_SELCHANGE:
            {
                HWND hwndList = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LISTBOX);

                // Get selected index.
                int lbItem = (int)SendMessage(hwndList, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);

                // Get item data.
                int i = (int)SendMessage(hwndList, LB_GETITEMDATA, lbItem, 0);

                // Do something with the data from Roster[i]
                TCHAR buff[MAX_PATH];
                StringCbPrintf(buff, ARRAYSIZE(buff),
                    TEXT("Position: %s\nGames played: %d\nGoals: %d"),
                    Roster[i].achPosition, Roster[i].nGamesPlayed,
                    Roster[i].nGoalsScored);

                SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_STATISTICS, buff);
                return TRUE;
            }
            }
        }


        case IDC_LISTBOX2:
        {
            switch (HIWORD(wParam))
            {
            case LBN_SELCHANGE:
            {
                HWND hwndList = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LISTBOX2);

                // Get selected index.
                int lbItem = (int)SendMessage(hwndList, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);

                // Get item data.
                int i = (int)SendMessage(hwndList, LB_GETITEMDATA, lbItem, 0);

                // Do something with the data from Roster[i]
                TCHAR buff[MAX_PATH];
                StringCbPrintf(buff, ARRAYSIZE(buff),
                    TEXT("Position: %s\nGames played: %d\nGoals: %d"),
                    HighSpeed[i].achPosition, HighSpeed[i].nGamesPlayed,
                    HighSpeed[i].nGoalsScored);

                SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_STATISTICS, buff);
                return TRUE;
            }
            }
        }

        return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Show your [mcve]. We are not even 100% sure what framework you are using because there are many to choose from. Is this just the windows api, using the `c` interface?

Comment: There's no difference with a non-owned (parent) window than a child window in terms of adding controls.

Comment: Using an example from Microsoft, I am able to create a child window with the list box.  I now need to create a list box within the parent window.